# Inkscape 0.92.2 compilation: links with two libMagick versions

Tags: linux, compilation, imagemagick, inkscape

I've compiled Inkscape 0.92.2 (on Slackware64-current Linux), and I can't export to PNG.

I found some references that libpng could be the culprit. Indeed, I found that the inkscape executable was linked with two versions of libpng (1.5 and 1.6).

A lot of tracing and debugging showed that the probleem seems to be that the executable is linked with two versions of libMagick (6 and 7), which import different versions of libpng.

Checking the Inkscape config.log file shows that indeed both libs are accessed:

`pkg_cv_IMAGEMAGICK_LIBS='-lMagick++-6.Q16 -lMagickWand-7.Q16HDRI -lMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI'`

**Edit:** As per emcconville's suggestion, I added `--with-magick-plus-plus=yes` and recompiled everything (both ImageMagick and Inkscape. No luck though:

```
$ ldd /usr/bin/inkscape | grep Magick
    libMagick++-6.Q16.so.5 => /usr/lib64/libMagick++-6.Q16.so.5 (0x00007f5ee46f3000)
    libMagickWand-6.Q16.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libMagickWand-6.Q16.so.2 (0x00007f5ee43d3000)
    libMagickCore-6.Q16.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libMagickCore-6.Q16.so.2 (0x00007f5ee3d23000)
    libMagickWand-7.Q16HDRI.so.5 => /usr/lib64/libMagickWand-7.Q16HDRI.so.5 (0x00007f5ee2e9b000)
    libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.so.5 => /usr/lib64/libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.so.5 (0x00007f5ee27a3000)
```

Maybe there's another library pulling in version 6. Though I can't seem to find which.

**Edit2:** Before applying emcconville's steps, I wanted to understand what was going on...

These are the actual libs and their links:

```
libMagick++                         so -> so.5.0.0
                                    so.5 -> so.5.0.0
                                    so.5.0.0
libMagick++-6.Q16           a   la  so -> so.5.0.0
                                    so.5 -> so.5.0.0
                                    so.5.0.0
libMagick++-7.Q16HDRI       a   la  so -> so.4.0.0
                                    so.4 -> so.4.0.0
                                    so.4.0.0
libMagickCore-6.Q16         a   la  so -> so.2.0.0
                                    so.2 -> so.2.0.0
                                    so.2.0.0
libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI     a   la  so -> so.5.0.0
                                    so.5 -> so.5.0.0
                                    so.5.0.0
libMagickWand-6.Q16         a   la  so -> so.2.0.0
                                    so.2 -> so.2.0.0
                                    so.2.0.0
libMagickWand-7.Q16HDRI     a   la  so -> so.5.0.0
                                    so.5 -> so.5.0.0
                                    so.5.0.0
libMagickCore                       so -> so.5.0.0
                                    so.5 -> so.5.0.0
                                    so.5.0.0
libMagickWand                       so -> so.5.0.0
                                    so.5 -> so.5.0.0
                                    so.5.0.0
```

This seems acceptable, except for the (unversioned) `libMagic++`, `libMagickCore`, and `libMagicWand` which I suspect are version 5.xxx and can be removed.

The .PC files are a little more complicated:

```
---- Version 6 pc files ---------Version 7 pc files ------
ImageMagick-6.Q16.pc        ImageMagick-7.Q16HDRI.pc
ImageMagick++-6.Q16.pc
Magick++-6.Q16.pc           Magick++-7.Q16HDRI.pc
MagickCore-6.Q16.pc         MagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.pc
MagickWand-6.Q16.pc         MagickWand-7.Q16HDRI.pc

--- Relationships:
ImageMagick.pc          -> ImageMagick-6.Q16.pc
Magick++.pc             is same as Magick++-7.Q16HDRI.pc (not a link!)
MagickCore.pc           is same as MagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.pc (not a link!)
MagickWand.pc           is same as MagickWand-7.Q16HDRI.pc (not a link!)
```

Note: ImageMagic.pc is pointing to version 6,
and there is no ImageMagick++-7.Q16HDRI.pc generated (even enabling the ++ compile option)

**Edit3:** Today I recompiled the last version of ImageMagick once again, this time monitoring much more closely which files it generates, and installs. @emcconville's suggestion to use symlinks for the pc-files does not seem to be entirely practical, as each install will overwrite those symlinks.
(see the last table in edit2). Still, while this system is as it is, there doesn't seem any other solution.

Comment: Did you configure/install ImageMagick-7 with CPP libraries (`--with-magick-plus-plus=yes`)?

Comment: Mmm. No I didn't. Compiling while I write... done. I checked the installed libs and don't see any new files. I'm recompiling inkscope now. Will report the results.

Comment: @emcconville - no luck it seems. I've update the original post.

Comment: I'm suspecting that this is related to some `.pc` files that wasn't removed. What is the output of `pkg-config --libs ImageMagick ImageMagick++`? If IM-6 & IM-7 libraries are both shown, you may have a bigger problem at hand.

Comment: Yes, both are present - how is that even possible? It's ImageMagick++ which pulls in the wrong version. `$ pkg-config --libs ImageMagick ImageMagick++
-lMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI -lMagick++-6.Q16 -lMagickWand-7.Q16HDRI -lMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI`

Comment: I'll analyze a bit more, but, as shown in the *edit2* above, the lack of the version 7 libMagick***.pc is strange.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what's going on, but it's more of a "hunch" than an answer.

I'm suspecting that an extra `.pc` script is floating around, and you just need to delete it.

1. Find the location of `ImageMagick.pc` & `ImageMagick++.pc`. This is usually under `/usr/share/pkgconfig/`, `/usr/local/share/pkgconfig/`, `/usr/lib/pkgconfig/`, `/usr/lib64/pkgconfig/`, & etc etc etc.

   Don't just stop at the first match, but scan everything with `locate`, or `find` utility.

   ```sh
   find /usr/ -name "ImageMagick*.pc" -type f
   ```
2. You should have a list that looks something like ....

   ```sh
   /usr/local/share/pkgconfig/ImageMagick++.pc
   /usr/local/share/pkgconfig/ImageMagick.pc
   /usr/local/share/pkgconfig/ImageMagick++-6.Q16.pc
   /usr/local/share/pkgconfig/ImageMagick-6.Q16.pc
   /usr/local/share/pkgconfig/ImageMagick++-7.Q16HDRI.pc
   /usr/local/share/pkgconfig/ImageMagick-7.Q16HDRI.pc
   ```
3. Nuke the offending files.

   ```sh
   # Create a backup place
   mkdir -p ~/backups
   # Archive `.pc' files for future investigations.
   gzip < /usr/local/share/pkgconfig/ImageMagick.pc > ~/backups/ImageMagick.pc.gz
   gzip < /usr/local/share/pkgconfig/ImageMagick++.pc > ~/backups/ImageMagick++.pc.gz
   # Remove
   sudo rm /usr/local/share/pkgconfig/ImageMagick.pc
   sudo rm /usr/local/share/pkgconfig/ImageMagick++.pc
   # Repeat as nessasry for duplicate instances,
   # but KEEP files with version prefixes (i.e `-6.Q16' & `-7.Q16HDRI')
   ```
4. Create symbolic links (assuming ImageMagick-7 is the default version for your system).

   ```sh
   sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/pkgconfig/ImageMagick-7.Q16HDRI.pc /usr/local/share/pkgconfig/ImageMagick.pc
   sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/pkgconfig/ImageMagick++-7.Q16HDRI.pc /usr/local/share/pkgconfig/ImageMagick++.pc
   ```
5. Rebuild inkscape, and confirm issue is resolved.
6. **Write a note to your future self describing what you did, and steps repeat/restore**. Some programs haven't migrated to IM-7, so it's more than possible that you'll need to updated the generic `.pc` files to point to IM-6 (or other way around).

Comment: I apologize for the delay. I noticed that there were some pc files missing, and some strange versions in the Magick files themselves (and one of the ++ files wasn't generated). I did not want to do your suggestions without understanding what I am doing. I'm somewhat calmer now and I'll report as soon as I have this sorted. Thanks already!

Comment: did some more research today. Updating original mail under *edit3*